# Visual studio 2010 beta 2 problem

Tags: visual-studio

I've been messing around with VS2010 beta 2 (ultimate) on windows7 and already I have a nasty problem - when I try to run devenv it's only shows me very-nice-beta2 splash screen and cpu usage of devenv process run to sky.

If thats can help - on machine i have already vs2008 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and it is a command:
Type “devenv /resetuserdata” in Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt
It will help you

Answer (score 0):

Not working. I notice that vs2010 starts only when devenv process use 20MB of memory (starts with 7mb, then slowly allocating to 20mb - then puff - 100mb and evrything ok). it wasnt be a problem if whole procces doesnt take 40 minutes ;/